Delayed POST requests to login endpoint
I have a python web app running behind nginx.
It logs all requests to non-static content.
Before this logging happens, I authenticate the user by checking the session cookie.
If it's valid, the logging output will include the user's id.
If the user isn't logged in, the logging output will say "None" for user id.
When the user hits the login endpoint, the logging happens before a new session is created.
So because there's no session cookie yet, user id in the logging output will be None.
So it's normal to see lines like this in the log (edited for brevity):
2024-01-10 16:00:28,204 /api/login None

This just means someone (whose identity wasn't yet known when the logging happened) has just logged in.
Their user name will be logged separately shortly after as part of handling the login request.
However, I frequently see requests to /api/login by a user who is already logged in.
For example:
2024-01-18 12:40:40,381 /api/login 123

This output can only happen if there was already a valid session cookie.
It should be impossible to hit the /api/login endpoint if you're already logged in.
The only page that can make requests to /api/login will redirect you to / if you're already logged in.
Of course nothing is stopping the user from making requests manually through the console or otherwise, but this occurs too often to be someone just messing around.
These mysterious requests to /api/login by an already logged-in user usually happen 10-60s after they login.
This means it's not just someone accidentally double pressing the login button.
So first there's a normal request that logs None for user id, as expected, and then there can be an additional one, delayed by up to a minute.
This doesn't always happen. For some users it doesn't happen at all.
I can't recreate it with my own account.
It does happen for a team member's account.
I confirmed that the delayed "extra" request is coming from his IP, so it doesn't seem like anything nefarious is going on.
The extra request is passing the same username as the original one (though I found one instance where it was passing a different user name, but one belonging to the same individual who has multiple accounts).
I tried using the same browser as them with the same settings and extensions, and I still can't recreate it.
I messed with network throttling and password managers and still can't recreate it.
I've heard of chrome sending multiple GET requests in some situations, but this is different.
This is a POST endpoint, and the extra requests can arrive quite late, after the user has already logged in and even made several other successful requests after having logged in.
I haven't noticed anything similar for any other endpoints.
What can be the reason for this?
